# PHP Query, get the value of a default serial value of newly created record

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

For a Quiz website, I am creating a record for a question, and want to get it's questionid straight after so I can use it in creating answer records. The questionid created at INSERT is a serial value automatically generated.

I am new to PHP and cannot figure out how I may get this value, as this id is the only unique way to id this newly created record. Is there anyway to do so?

This is my code for creating the new record.

```
$questioncreatequery = pg_query("INSERT INTO question (questionid, quizid, questiontype, qdescription, qfilelocation, noofanswers, answertype) VALUES( default, '".$thisquizid."', '".$questiontype."', '".$qdescription."', '".$qfilelocation."', '".$noofanswers."', '".$answertype."')");
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can use mysql_insert_id. link:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: `pg_query()` is for PostgreSQL, so `mysql_insert_id()` won't work.

Comment: @Grumpy This is postgresql, not mysql.

Comment: oops, my bad, i just looked at php sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you need is to use the `RETURNING` clause, to return a value from your `INSERT` statement like that:

```
$questioncreatequery = pg_query("INSERT INTO question (questionid, quizid, questiontype, qdescription, qfilelocation, noofanswers, answertype) VALUES( default, '".$thisquizid."', '".$questiontype."', '".$qdescription."', '".$qfilelocation."', '".$noofanswers."', '".$answertype."') RETURNING questionid");
```

Then you can use `$questioncreatequery` just like any query result and get your value:

```
  $row = pg_fetch_assoc($questioncreatequery);
  echo $row['questionid']; // <= this is the value you want
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and very handy for future reference, thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. Note that you can use even return multiple columns (`RETURNING questionid, quizid, qdescription`). It behaves very similar to `SELECT`.

Comment: And you can return multiple rows too.  So if you did this with a multiple insert you'd get back all the questionids in order you put them in.